# Need help with simple Eclipse Android application coding

Tags: android, eclipse

I have little knowledge of java scripting, and need help making my application work.  I am trying to create a simple counter with 2 buttons (up and down) and a text displaying the count.  I want the up button to add 1 to the count, and the down button to subtract 1 from the count.

I cannot figure out how to tie a value to my text box, and how to make the buttons add or subtract that value, do I need to create a variable for the count?

I essentially want button1's onClick to sum(count + 1)
and button2's onClick to sum(count - 1)

I have figured out how to use the onClickListener, and have made it do some simple showToastMessage applications, but I am stuck on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,
Caleb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what you want to do is have a Handler which is in charge of updating the textview.  So whenever the button is clicked you send a message(some form of data) to the Handler and then the handler will update the text view with that data received from the message. Here is a simple example of how to use Handler in Android: [Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I had no clue what to look for as far as solutions went, this will definately help me out.